# While trying to consolidate txt file in excel I'm getting Run time error 1004

Tags: vba, excel

My target is to export txt files in a folder and consolidate it into one excel sheet also get the file name and the saved date of the txt files in separate column respectively.

While trying to consolidate txt files in a folder in excel by below code, I'm getting a runtime error 1004 in **.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=True** why I'm getting the error?

```
Sub test()

 Dim wbk As Workbook, wksht As Worksheet
    Dim xStrPath As String
    Dim xFileDialog As FileDialog
    Dim xFile As String
    Dim xFiles As New Collection
    Dim I As Long

    Set xFileDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    xFileDialog.AllowMultiSelect = False
    xFileDialog.Title = "Select a folder"
    If xFileDialog.Show = -1 Then
        xStrPath = xFileDialog.SelectedItems(1)
    End If
    If xStrPath = "" Then Exit Sub

    If Right(xStrPath, 1) <> "\" Then xStrPath = xStrPath & "\"
    xFile = Dir(xStrPath & "*.txt")
    If xFile = "" Then
        MsgBox "No files found", vbInformation, "eBay"
        Exit Sub
    End If

Workbooks.Add
Set wbk = ActiveWorkbook
Set wksht = ActiveSheet

Do While xFile <> ""
        xFiles.Add xFile, xFile
        xFile = Dir()
Loop

If xFiles.Count > 0 Then

For I = 1 To xFiles.Count
'On Error Resume Next
    With wksht.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & xFile, Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
    .Name = xFile
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    .TextFilePlatform = 65001
    .TextFileStartRow = 1
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierNone
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
    .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=True

    End With

Next
End If

End Sub
```

[image: error]

Is there any other simple way?

Comment: At what line do you get the error?

Comment: @DavidG  at this line  .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=True

Comment: Yes I should be using With wksht.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & xStrPath & xFiles.Item(I), Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
   and  .Name = xFiles.Item(I)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the fix thank you all for the help :)

```
With wksht.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & xStrPath & xFiles.Item(I), Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
.Name = xFiles.Item(I)
```